# REST API Endpoint for Retrieving Empty Object

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource

I have a REST API endpoint for creating an empty object. What is the "standard" url scheme for this GET method? I'm currently using a factory in an angularjs app to make the call to the server.

Right now I have the following scheme:

```
GET 
Item/new/
```

My `$resource`:

```
 ngServices.factory("TESTfactory", function ($resource) {
                    return $resource("testNewItem/new", {}, {
                            create: {method: 'GET'}
                        }
                }
```

A successful call to the above resource:

```
$scope.newItem = TESTfactory.newItem.create();
```

Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

I've looked at the following links, which did not specifically list a url scheme for getting empty objects:

1. [REST API Overview](http://developers.amiando.com/index.php/REST_API_Overview)
2. [Quick Reference section in this doc](https://parse.com/docs/rest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GET method should *never* create something. GET is supposed to be nullipotent, which means that it should have no side-effects. Creating a resource is certainly a side effect.

So, the standard http call would be

```
POST 
Items/create
```

or

```
POST
Items/new
```

or better yet just

```
POST
Items/
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants a *template* object - as in, his repository suffers no change, no resource is created; he wants a new instance that provides the model.